# Automatize conversion of .FBX to .OBJ/.MTL using Blender

Tags: scripting, file-format, conversion

I have a large number of files in .FBX format that I would like to convert to the Wavefront .OBJ/.MTL format. I can easily do this in Blender by Importing/Exporting but I need to be able to do this automatically, ideally using a Python script.

I have no experience using the Blender API. Could you give me a code snippet that achieves this conversion?